# How to set SKProductsRequest time out sec ? What is the default timeout sec for SKProductsRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timeout, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to set timeout for SKProductsRequest ?
Any one know the default timeout for SKProductsRequest ?

Answer (score 6):

There is no open apple's api to set [SKProductRequests](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsRequest/) timeout directly,
but you can implement some simple methods to setup it manually. In this case you need to keep a strong reference to your SKProductsRequest instance:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
```

Then create your request and use [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:)
method to stop it in needed time interval:

```
self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[StoreKitManager productsIDSet]];
self.productsRequest .delegate = self;
[self.productsRequest  start];
[self setupTimeout];

- (void)cancelTimeout {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(stopRequest) object:nil];

}

- (void)setupTimeout {
    [self cancelTimeout];
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopRequest) withObject:self afterDelay:30.0f];
}

- (void)stopRequest {
    [self.productsRequest cancel];
}
```

And do not forget to cancel timeout in your delegates:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    [self cancelTimeout];
}

- (void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request {
    [self cancelTimeout];
}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self cancelTimeout];
}
```